# In Corona SDK how to add label(text) to images?

Tags: coronasdk

In corona SDK how to add label(text) to images

I have created my image as follow

```
    local item = display.newImageRect('images/foo.png',70,70);
    item.x = 50;
    item.y = 50;
```

How to add a text to the image?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add text to the image, so it appears to "stick" to the image, you could create the object (as you have) and also the text object directly above it. Then, create a group and stick them both in it.

Here is an example of how that could be done:

```
local myGroup = display.newGroup()

local item = display.newImageRect('images/foo.png',70,70)
item.x = 50
item.y = 50

local text = display.newText( "My Text", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 18 )
text:setTextColor( 0, 0, 0, 255 )

-- insert items into group, in the order you want them displayed:
myGroup:insert( item )
myGroup:insert( text )
```

Then, to move it around, just modify the x/y of 'myGroup'.

Hope that helps!