# In Lua how to associate a numeric value to an object

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have just started coding in Lua(corona). I have an image.

```
local egg=display.newImage("egg.jpg")
```

Now I want to display a random number on the image and associate that image with it. Like if this image collides with another object, I need to retrieve the value of the random number. How can this be done?

Comment: Draw text over the image, using whatever corona gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lua, you can just add properties to any object.

```
local myRandomNumber = math.Random()
local egg = display.newImage("egg.jpg")
egg.numberValue = myRandomNumber
```

So to retrieve that value you would just access the numberValue property

To know more about random numbers you can read here

http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answer. But I am getting an error. "attempt to call field 'Random' (a nil value). Do I have to include the Math library like in java and if so how does one do it in lua...Thankyou once again!!!

Comment: And also is there a way to display the number value on the image?

Comment: There is a typo in his post, it should be math.random() - You can read more here: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/math/random.html

Comment: As for how to display a number on the image, here is a helpful tip using groups (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408687/in-corona-sdk-how-to-add-labeltext-to-images), alternatively you could change the image to a button widget with a text label (https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newButton.html). I would recommend the grouping over the button though

Comment: also to include librarys in lua, you use "require". See here (https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/package/require.html)